# Django, creating a new model instance from view throws ValidationError

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following **model**:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    licenses = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default="")
```

as you see above I want to allow `datetime` and `licenses` to be nothing.

I want to create a new instance of this model in my view with the following code:

```
Machine.objects.create(name=machine_name, user=user_name, mail=user_mail)
```

But I get

```
ValidationError at /update
[u"'' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

At the same time the following line works fine if run in DB directly:

```
INSERT INTO `xxx`.`xxx` (`name`, `user`, `mail`) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

I don't understand why django wants me to enter the *datetime-elements* even if I have specified that null is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `default=""` for datetime field.

```
datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

Even though you have specified `blank=True` and `null=True` django will try to set default value when nothing specified. But as default is not in expected format, that causes the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I really missed this.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove  `default = ""` from your datetime field .
if you want to fill current time into datetime filed while making create entry in db you can use

```
auto_now_add=True
```

for more info you can go to [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/)